# How to fix Firefox update error in Selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, updates

Every time my firefox updates my tests don't run and give an error like "version of this program has been updated".I don't want to set firefox tools to "Never check for updates" because newer versions run well on my computer.How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Web driver is usually updated when a new version of Firefox is updated. You really have no option other than to stop Firefox updating, and then manually doing it when web driver is released.